# Conversión de fecha en Java

Tags: java, apache

Estoy recibiendo una fecha desde un archivo Excel estoy utilizando Apache POI y mediante el método `getStringCellValue()` estoy almacenando en una variable la fecha, la imprimo y me da el siguiente formato `43525`.

Esto lo he visto antes en PHP, pero no se como lo convierto a `Date` en Java. ¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saludos puedes intentar algo así:

```
DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
String cellStringValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(0));
System.out.println ("Fecha: " + cellStringValue);
```

esto tomará el formato de la celda(fecha, numérico,etc), también te sugiero revisar esto: [getDateCellValue()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCell.html#getDateCellValue())

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, funciona perfecto!!